# Grails, will different package on bootstrap leads creating user unsuccessful?

Tags: grails, grails-3.3

I am trying to create some user for login testing. So that, I have created some user on bootstrap.

```
User user = new User(username: 'user', userPassword: 'user', userEmail: 'user@user.com').save()
```

Then I try to login. The result was unsuccessful. Even database got no record on the user I have create on BootStrap.groovy

Will different package on bootstrap with my domains that affects?

Domain Package

```
package com.abc.myapp
```

BootStrap Package

```
package myapp
```

or is there any other possibility on this *"bootstrap creating user error"*

Comment: Ensure the insert didn't fail by adding the following to save, `save(failOnError: true)`, also, you're going to end up with a lot of duplicate users with this in place unless you have relevant database constraints in place or you're rebuilding the db on boot.

Comment: Thanks for that !! Finally I can know whats going on. The code is very useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap is not related to package.This file can be used for any custom logic you want to happen during application startup.Excellent use of the file is to preload some data in our database.

```
 class BootStrap { 
            def init = { servletContext ->
            new User(username:'user',userPassword:'user',userEmail:'user@user.com').save(failOnError: true)
                      }
}
```

save(failOnError: true) will give you the cause if it fails to save data.To avoid duplicate data creation use constrain in you domain class .

```
static constraints = {
        username unique: true, blank: false
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and reminder. The code is useful.